# FitSharp - Decision Table

Tags: fitnesse

I am using Fit and FitSharp/.NET, and want to implement a decision table.
Based on the name of a 'page' I want to call the appropriate defined procedure to check it.

I want something like:

```
$define Page {Page 2}
$define Action {}

|${Page}|Action?|
|Page 1|verify page 1|
|Page 2|verify page 2|
|Page 3|verify page 3|


|${Action}| #should execute |verify page 2|
```

I want the table to go through each column and where the appropriate page is found, then return the procedure name to call. Then call the procedure.

Any ideas how  I could do this? I didnt want to use slim as it rewuires the 'script' statement simple fixture calls and wanted to avoid having to type that in.

Is TableFixture available in fitSharp? It doesnt look like it is according to help pages.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Kind Regards,

Rahul Dixit

Answer (score 0):

FitSharp has no such capability. I have to write my own fixture to do this.